# JOptionPane error with string and variable concatenation

Tags: java, compiler-errors, joptionpane

I'm trying to make somewhat of a calculator for a programming class that I am in that incorporates user input and then does math. I have chosen to use `JOptionPane` for the user input portion of this assignment and everything is going smoothly until I ask Java to concatenate strings with some previously defined variables in a `JOptionPane` message dialog.
I am using DrJava.

I am receiving the error:

```
Error: unexpected type
  required: class
  found:    value
```

Here is my code:

```
(Line 1) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you! Here are your results:\n"+

(2)               "The addition of "+fnum+" and "+snum+" is "(fnum+snum)"\n"+

(3)               "The subtraction of "+fnum+" and "+snum+" is "+(5-3));
```

I am receiving the error on line two with my cursor in between fnum and + in (fnum+snum)

The variables have been defined and this process works properly using the System.out.println method.

Any suggestions on what's going on?

Comment: You are missing some `+` signs here: `" is "(fnum+snum)"\n"` it should be `" is " + (fnum+snum) + "\n"`

Comment: Gosh I feel foolish! I realize that now. Well thanks for the help anyways. I've only been programming for about two weeks so I'm still making those mistakes lol

Answer (score 0):

```
OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you! Here are your results:\n"+
"The addition of "+fnum+" and "+snum+" is "+(fnum+snum)+"\n"+
"The subtraction of "+fnum+" and "+snum+" is "+(5-3));
```

Comment: Gosh I feel foolish! I realize that now. Well thanks for the help anyways. I've only been programming for about two weeks so I'm still making those mistakes lol

Comment: You're welcome.
You should use an IDE supporting the java syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the **culprit** ,

```
(2) "The addition of "+fnum+" and "+snum+" is "(fnum+snum)"\n"+
```

Instead of this use this

```
(2) "The addition of "+fnum+" and "+snum+" is "+(fnum+snum)+"\n"+
```